# Equivalent of pick command in linux

Tags: linux-mint, command

OS: Linux Mint 14

Is there an equivalent of the `pick` command available in Linux? Pick command is the one where for each given argument, it asks yes/no and prints the selection to stdout. This script is commonly described in unix books (unix power tools).

Comment: I don't know `pick` but maybe you can achieve the same with `grep`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That utility is just a little shell script, not – as far as I know – anything that is regularly shipped with Unix systems or Linux distributions.

You can find it in the Examples section on O'Reilly's site: [description](http://examples.oreilly.de/english_examples/upt3/#pick), [script itself](http://examples.oreilly.de/english_examples/upt3/split/pick). Save it to a file somewhere in your `$PATH` and make it executable and you're ready to go.